# Why std::move is not working with std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am unable to compile the below program.

```
void toSin(std::list<double>&& list)
{
    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), [](double& x)
    {
        x = sin(x);
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::list<double> list;
    const double pi = 3.141592;
    const double epsilon = 0.0000001;
    for (double x = 0.0; x < 2 * pi + epsilon; x = x + pi / 16)
    {
        list.push_back(x);
    }
    // Start thread
    std::thread th(toSin, std::move(list));
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I get > error C2664: '`void (std::list<double,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&)`' : cannot convert argument 1 from '`std::list<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>`' to '`std::list<double,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&`'

Comment: Reproduce I cannot. Which version of visual studio are you using? Mind you, I added in a bunch of missing headers.

Comment: The line `std::thread th(toSin, std::move(list));` implies that you should not iterator over `list` beyond that point, since it's moved away. But you try to iterate over it on the very next line.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013

Comment: 2013 is missing a lot of C++ 11 support. Compiles in 2015, but shouldn't run the way you want. See if you can upgrade. Also heed @FrançoisAndrieux's warning.

Comment: You probably want **l-value** reference instead of r-value reference for `toSin`, and then `std::thread th(toSin, std::ref(list));`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @ François Andrieux. However, this code works perfectly fine

Comment: In additoin to FrançoisAndrieux comment, If you expect to use same list, you will have UB as concurrent access is not synchronized (mutex, ...).

Comment: As far as I know, STL is not thread-safe for write.

Comment: This code compiles in VS2013. However, after executing the line test(std:: move(list));, I could still see the size of the list is 1.

void test(std::list<double> && list)
{
 
}

int main()
{
        std::list<double> list;
 test(std::move(list));
}

Comment: The code compiles with gcc 5.4.0. With `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 main.cpp -lpthread` gives no errors and no warnings after I included the appropriate header files.

Comment: Looks like you have a case where the compiler sees [better advantage in not `move`ing](http://ideone.com/lIhxm0), but with a [more complicated case based on your question...](http://ideone.com/rjWOWg) In other words don't count on it. [Assume nothing about the state of the moved from other than you can destroy it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850196/what-lasts-after-using-stdmove-c11).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your compiler is wrong here.  A decayed (copied) value type should be bindable to an rvalue reference.

Anyway take a look at [this quote from the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

> 3) Creates new std::thread object and associates it with a thread of execution. The new thread of execution starts executing
>
> ```
> std::invoke(decay_copy(std::forward<Function>(f)), decay_copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
> ```

Basically anything you pass as an argument to the constructor of `std::thread` will be copied as a function argument to the function.

Also know that your function will work just fine if you make it accept the `std::list` variable by value instead of by rvalue reference.  See [Correct usage of rvalue references as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673889/correct-usage-of-rvalue-references-as-parameters) for more

---

If your intent is to pass a reference to a variable to a thread function, the way I do it usually is with a lambda

```
std::list<double> lst;
auto th = std::thread{[&lst]() {
    toSin(lst);
}};
```

But you can also use `std::ref` for the same effect.  I just personally feel the lambda approach is clearer.

```
std::list<double> lst;
auto th = std::thread{toSin, std::ref(lst)};
```

---

[Also as correctly pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911484/why-stdmove-is-not-working-with-stdlist/44911674#comment76799617_44911484), you have a race condition in your code that you should prevent with a `mutex`, or wait for the thread to finish

```
auto th = std::thread{[&lst]() {
    toSin(lst);
}};
th.join();

// then iterate and print out
```

Comment: Updated the code above, I just wanted to have a unique memory to the worker thread to avoid synchronization issues.

Comment: @NARESHKITTUR if you do that however, how do you intend to print out the list later on in the main thread?

Comment: True, I will not be able to use the list in the main thread. I will have to process/print the list in the worker thread itself. So to get around this problem I should be passing the list by reference with the mutex.

Comment: @NARESHKITTUR correct, or wait for the thread to finish via `.join()`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you maybe miss some `#include`, that code works on Visual Studio 2015

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <thread>
void toSin(std::list<double>&& list)
{
    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), [](double& x)
    {
        x = sin(x);
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::list<double> list;
    const double pi = 3.141592;
    const double epsilon = 0.0000001;
    for (double x = 0.0; x < 2 * pi + epsilon; x = x + pi / 16)
    {
        list.push_back(x);
    }
    // Start thread
    std::thread th(toSin, std::move(list));
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 is not Visual Studio 2013. 2013 has gaping holes in its c++11 support. Odds are good that it doesn't compile. I don't have easy access to 2013, couldn't see the point of upgrading until the holes were filled, so I don't have a copy to try it out.